Analog current monitoring of a switching load
I have a circuit that I am trying to check if the current drops. My load can be simplified to 3 parallel resistors, so if one ever breaks the current will reduce and then the power should be shut off as a result. I am using a current sensing amplifier to measure the voltage drop across a small resistor between the power and the load. I have this connected to a comparator that will detect if the voltage drops below a certain threshold and send a signal to a SSR that will shut down the circuit.
My issue is that power is being sent to the load as a square wave coming from a 555 timer, so the power is constantly cycling between an on and off state. When the power switches off the current sensing amplifier reads this as low current and shuts off the circuit permanently.
I am not sure how to handle this problem, so hopefully one of you could provide some ideas on how to rectify the problem. I have attached a schematic showing the relevant parts of my circuit. Also, I am looking for analog solutions only, therefore I will not use a microcontroller for this project.

Update: I have included oscilloscope output of U7 & U8 under normal conditions. To acquire these images I had to disconnect U8 from U10.



What's the purpose of D9 and D10?

Please provide oscillograms of load current, U7.1 and U8.1.

@winny D9, D10, and D13 exist to provide isolation between each component thereby reducing noise. Also, what is an oscillogram? Is that the same as an oscilloscope? Do you want to see what the outputs of each chip are?

I can't see any way that this will work as you expect it to because, from what I can see, the 74LVC1G384GW will only ever be enabled when the current is zero or below the upper threshold. Plus you are trying to drive a BJT without a gate resistor.

@Andyaka I did make a mistake in the schematic, my + & - I/P for U8 was flipped, but I updated the schematic. When the current drops U8 switches from low to high voltage and opens the circuit at U10. I have gotten this to work with a non switching load power.

I don't see how your diodes would isolate nor provide any real noise suppression. If you drop 5 V significantly, they are no longer forward biased and will only capacitively couple your HF noise though them. An oscillogram is the waveform capture from an oscilloscope.

@winny Regardless of if the diodes do what I think they do, it shouldn't affect the function of the chips they're attached to (right?). I added the pictures you asked for, sorry about the quality this is as good as I could get.

why downvote this question?

Good. Now, you have a 4 channel scope so you can check each stage of your circuit. Does your amplifier amplify the current sense signal to the correct level? Does your comparator trigger at your setpoint? Does your analog switch switch as intended? Does your SSR switch off as intended?

@winny Yes, each of those things are working correctly. The issue is that downwards spike shown on U7. That is a product of the 555 timer and cannot be removed. I need U8 to not respond to that sudden drop because right now it does and it shuts off the entire circuit.
